# Saving data retrieved using BeautifulSoup into an array

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

*Hi guys,
I'm new to BeautifulSoup and I don't really understand how to extract data.
I would like to extract the first ten titles of the amazon bestseller list and store it into an array.

My goal is to create a Top 10 list of amazon and replicate the process over and over for different categories. I wanna extract only the "title" of the products.

Here is my code:
*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}
url_amazon = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Best-Sellers-Electronics/zgbs/electronics"
response = requests.get(url_amazon, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

print(soup.prettify())

title = soup.find("h1", class_ = "a-size-large a-spacing-medium zg-margin-left-15 a-text-bold").text
print(title)


titles = []

for item in soup.findAll("div", attrs = {"class" : "a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-right"}):
    name = item.find("div", attrs = {"class" : "p13n-sc-truncated"})
    if name is not None:
        titles.append(name.text)
    else:
        titles.append("unknown title")

print(len(titles))

for i in titles:
    print(i)
```

The output is:
"unknown title"

Comment: It would be useful if you could clarify your question. What happens when you run your code? In what way does this differ from your desired outcome?

Comment: What error(s) did you encounter with this code?

Comment: Please do not post the full code, create a [mre]

Comment: The output is: "unknown title" since I think that I'm not extracting anything.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks Andreas :)

Comment: the data might be dynamic so you'll need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to extract it

Comment: You need to use selenium-chromedriver as data is dynamic.@AndrèsTanesini

Comment: @Akshat Zala alright mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is that the CSS class in the line `name = item.find("div", attrs={"class": "p13n-sc-truncated"}` should be `p13n-sc-truncate`. Your second issue is that the class you use to find the items is too specific (to the first item). I found it more useful to search for list items with the class `zg-item-immersion`.

If you only want to list the first 10 items, you can add the `[:10]` slice specifier to your primary for loop. Putting it all together, we get:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9"
}
url_amazon = (
    "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Best-Sellers-Electronics/zgbs/electronics"
)
response = requests.get(url_amazon, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

print(soup.prettify())

title = soup.find(
    "h1", class_="a-size-large a-spacing-medium zg-margin-left-15 a-text-bold"
).text
print(title)


titles = []

for item in soup.findAll("li", attrs={"class": "zg-item-immersion"})[:10]:
    name = item.find("div", attrs={"class": "p13n-sc-truncate"})
    if name is not None:
        titles.append(name.text.strip())
    else:
        titles.append("unknown title")

print(len(titles))

for i in titles:
    print(i)
```

I used `name.text.strip()` in order to remove new-line characters and extra spaces.

It should be noted that this script is relatively fragile because Amazon could change the layout and class names at any time.

Comment: Gotcha :) I see. How can I prevent to make my script more flexible and avoid the issue? btw thank you for your answer :) I'm a newbie and I really appreciate any help/suggestions.